# SQL COUNT(*) count every table

Tags: mysql

When I do an SQL query with a COUNT(*) for example :

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM TABLE
```

It returns 44, this is the exact result. However I need to display something next to it for example :

```
SELECT COUNT(*), Cars 
FROM TABLEA 
INNER JOIN TABLEB 
ON TABLEA.Key = TABLEB.Key 
GROUP BY Cars
```

Except the COUNT(*) no longer displays 44 but 3071. I don't understand why it does that to me.
Here is the real SQL query, I don't know if I can provide my database on Stack Overflow:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as NBR, Formule
FROM elior_commande
INNER JOIN elior_menu ON numMenuCommande = numMenu
INNER JOIN elior_formule ON idFormule = numFormule
GROUP BY Formule;
```

I've already tried to LEFT JOIN but it display 2997.
When I "COUNT(*)" on "elior_commande", it display 44, that what I want.

Comment: The first query counts all the rows in 1 table. The second query counts all the related rows in the two tables for each car. Why would you expect the results to be similar?

Comment: What do you mean by it displaying 2997? Doesn't it display different counts for each Formulae?

Comment: @Barmar I don't know how to explain it, but I have a database, and when doing COUNT(*), my COUNT returns 2997 however in my elior_commande table I only have 44 entries.
I am still learning SQL and I don't understand why it returns me 2997 and not 44

Comment: Please add sample data and results to the question.

Answer (score 0):

When we join 2 tables the number of matching rows for any key is the product of the number of rows in each table.
In the following example we have 2 rows in each table so there are 2 * 2 = 4 matches.  One solution is to use count distinct.

> ```
> create table tableA(
> key_ int,
> cars varchar(10)
> );
> insert into tableA values
> (1,'Ford'),(1,'Ford');
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
>
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> create table tableB(
> key_ int,
> cars varchar(10)
> );
> insert into tableB values
> (1,'Ford'),(1,'Ford');
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
>
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> SELECT COUNT(*) "number", tableA.Cars 
> FROM tableA 
> INNER JOIN tableB 
> ON tableA.Key_ = tableB.Key_ 
> GROUP BY Cars
> ```
>
> ```
> number | Cars
> -----: | :---
>      4 | Ford
> ```

> ```
> SELECT COUNT(distinct tableA.cars) "number", tableA.Cars 
> FROM tableA 
> INNER JOIN tableB 
> ON tableA.Key_ = tableB.Key_ 
> GROUP BY Cars
> ```
>
> ```
> number | Cars
> -----: | :---
>      1 | Ford
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=4bee8595b87375f85eacf9ba776bb90a)*

Comment: What are those checkmarks supposed to mean?

Comment: @Barmar they're copied from DBfiddle and show success, 1 per DDL query. I generally remove them manually to make the answer more concise.